# Connect-Four Game in Scala

Tags: scala

I have to make a connect-four game using scala. I have attached the code but everytime the game runs and gets to row 3 it just continues to change the second rows entry instead of going to the next row. Any help would be appreciated. I found this code on [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27073660/connect-four-game-in-scala) on here and couldn't figure out how to get it to work:

```
// makes the board
val table = Array.fill(9,8)('-') 
var i = 0; 
while(i < 8){ 
  table(8)(i) = (i+'0').toChar 
  i = i+1;
}

// prints starting board
def printBoard(table: Array[Array[Char]]) { 
  table.foreach( x => println(x.mkString(" ")))
}


//player 1 moves
def playerMove1(){
  val move = readInt
  var currentRow1 = 7
  while (currentRow1 >= 0)
    if (table(currentRow1)(move) != ('-')) {
      currentRow1 = (currentRow1-1)
      table(currentRow1)(move) = ('X')
      return (player2)}
    } else {
      table(currentRow1)(move) =  ('X')
      return (player2)
    }
}

//player 2 moves
def playerMove2(){
  val move = readInt
  var currentRow2 = 7
  while (currentRow2 >= 0)
    if (table(currentRow2)(move) != ('-')) {
      currentRow2 = (currentRow2-1)
      table(currentRow2)(move) = ('O')
      return (player1)}
    } else {
      table(currentRow2)(move) =  ('O')
      return (player1)
    }
}

//player 1
def player1(){
    printBoard(table)
    println("Player 1 it is your turn. Choose a column 0-7")
    playerMove1()
}

//player 2
def player2(){
    printBoard(table)
    println("Player 2 it is your turn. Choose a column 0-7")
    playerMove2()
}

for (turn <- 1 to 32){
    player1
    player2
}
```

Comment: Please reference the mentioned thread, adjust the title and the first sentence - I just don't get what you want to say ....

Comment: sorry for not clarifying. When i run this code the bottom two rows will fill up, but when i go to enter a X or O in a column it just switches the second entry instead of going to the next row. heres the lonk to the other thread   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27073660/connect-four-game-in-scala

Comment: Strangely, this reminds me of [Stack Sort](https://xkcd.com/1185/). Back to topic: You seem to have an additional `}` before each `else` clause, so this code wouldn't compile. Also, at the end of both, the `then`-body and the `else`-body you return, so `currentRow1` / `currentRow2` will never be decremented further.

Answer (score 2):

I've tried to make your code readable and compiling and also tried to fix some logic.

However, I've never worked with Scala so this is just a first sketch where you might want to continue ...

Some functions can be merged and the currentRow needed a fix. See here:

```
object ConnectFour{
  val table = Array.fill(9,8)('-') 
  val currentRow = Array.fill(8)(8)

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    var i = 0; 
    while(i < 8) {
      table(8)(i) = (i+'0').toChar 
      i = i+1;
    }

    player(1)
  }

  def printBoard(table: Array[Array[Char]]) { 
    table.foreach( x => println(x.mkString(" ")))
  }

  def player(playerNr : Int){
    printBoard(table)
    println("Player " + playerNr + " it is your turn. Choose a column 0-7")
    var column = readAndVerifyInt

    var nextUser = 1 : Int
    var symbol = 'O' : Char

    if(playerNr == 1) {
        symbol = 'X'
        nextUser = 2
    }

    var curR = currentRow(column)
    while (curR >= 0) {
      if (table(curR)(column) != ('-')) {
        curR = curR-1
        currentRow(column) = curR
      }
      table(curR)(column) = symbol
      player(nextUser)
    }
  }

  def readAndVerifyInt() : Int = {
      var column = readInt
      if (column >= 0 && column <= 7) {
          return column
      } else {
          println(" > Please try again")
          return readAndVerifyInt
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your help, but I emailed my professor and he helped me.

Comment: I've fixed it never the less just for myself - the attached code works and is a little easier than yours ;)